# MousePressEvent not working on QPushbutton

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

so in my qtgui i want to know whenever someone is clicking (on any QObject or on the window),
Thus i'm using the MousePressEvent.
However when i'm clicking on QPushbuttons the event is not recognized

There is a simplier version of my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow,self).__init__()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.setStyleSheet("\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        #self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("#centralwidget{background-image: url(:/images/assets/back1.jpg);}")
        
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.timer = 5000
        
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")

        self.but1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1500, 500, 301, 51))
        self.but1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.but1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                "border-style: outset;""\n"
                " border-radius: 10px;"
                "border-width: 2px;"
                "border-color: gray;"
                "font: 18pt \"Adobe Pi Std\";\n"
                "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}\n"
                "QPushButton:pressed { border-style : inset; border-color:black}")
        self.but1.setObjectName("but1")
        self.but1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.addtimer())
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)


  def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        #super(Ui_MainWindow,self).mousePressEvent(event) i tried this but change nothing
        print("Clicked")

  def addtimer(self):
       self.timer+=5000
       print(self.timer)

def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.but1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Explore!"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i highly believe this problem is caused by bad inhertiance, but i can't figure out how to fix it.

If you wonder why i want to know whenever someone click, well the main purpose is to set a Qtimer that will close the window if no click occurs after x time

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is to determinate what kind of mouse event do u want to check then go to pyqt5 documentation and search what event does that (that's what i did) after that is just code the logic to detect that event.

```
#Below your other self.but1... u add this one to call the function each time u click
self.but1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent.MouseButtonPress))

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    #Here you check if the event u receive its the one you want to track
    if event == QMouseEvent.MouseButtonPress:
        print("Clicked")
```

Hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Well apprently it works thanks! However this method look a bit  "heavy" .Indeed, i may have a lot of buttons. i'm going to wait a bit, then if no one gives another solution i'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again

Comment: When a button is pressed it matches with QMouseEvent.MouseButtonPress which is the same than the number "2" if u take a look at the documentation. Just made a quick answer according to your problem.